# Relative import of local package with VS code

Tags: python, relative-import

I typically have a folder open in VS code which contain my python project with a `.venv` folder.

I placed my current project in such a way that I have to go back to the parent folder to find my other module.

```
workspace_folder
-- module_to_import
--- __init__.py
--- submodule1
---- __init__.py
-- project_currently_working_on
```

When I try to do a relative import as such

```
import ..module_to_import
```

I am getting a `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

I open the folder in VS code and configured the `launch.json` as

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module - name module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            // "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"},
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried this with `settings.json`

```
{
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "python.terminal.launchArgs": [
    ],
    "jupyter.interactiveWindow.creationMode": "perFile",
    "jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
    "notebook.confirmDeleteRunningCell": false,
    "jupyter.askForLargeDataFrames": false,
    "[cpp]": {
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": "off",
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace",
        "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true
    },
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["../module_to_import"], // <----- added
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "jupyter.interactiveWindow.textEditor.executeSelection": true,
}
```

To no avail.

If I put this instead `"python.analysis.extraPaths": [".."]`, I can see in the IDE the module, and no warning appear. However, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` when running the script:

```
import module_to_import // <--- IDE automatically proposes me this
from module_to_import import submodule1 // <--- Can even see it pop-up in the IDE
```

Then, I asked chatGPT which proposed to create a workspace in such a way that:

```
workspace_folder
-- module_to_import
-- project_currently_working_on
```

With the workspace configuration having:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}"]
    },  
}
```

Again, same `ModuleNotFoundError`.

When I try relative import, I can see all of the other projects/modules when typing `..`. However, I get again a `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` when running the script with:

```
import ..module_to_import // <--- IDE proposes a list of module after typing .. with the option of the module_to_import visible
```

Any idea how I could get a configuration that would allow me to easily add local module to my current project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3?rq=2

Comment: Not really, for my import to work, I need to add `sys.path.append('..')`. The file structure is also not the same. However, once I have the `sys.path.append('..')`, I can import as proposed in the link. My issue stern more from VS code configuration.

Comment: I'm currently on mobile so I wont try to type out a full answer right now, but Relative imports can only be used within a package, and they are Package relative, not Path relative. You should be able to do what you want with `pip install -e module_to_import` to install it into your venv, and then use absolute imports.

Comment: When doing this module install, is there some sort of revision going on, or it's just looking at whatever code is inside the current folder, e.g., `modle_to_import`?